# map.setClickable is not a function in ionic

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to get lat-long co-ordination when user clicks on map. However, when I tried to do so I’m getting an error like the following:

> **_this.map.on is not a function.**

I have also tried `this.map.one` but still I’m getting the same error.  Can any one help me? to set an on click event on map and get lat-long from map which is **JavaScript API based (not native) used on browser**.

I am also getting the following error in `setClickable`:

> **_this.map.setClickable is not a function.**

Here is my code:

```
initMap() {

    this.mapInitialised = true;

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      console.log("lat " + position.coords.latitude + " long " + position.coords.longitude)

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        clickableIcons: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: false,
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

       var longClick = google.maps.event.MAP_CLICK;

       this.map.on(longClick, function (latLng) {

        var selectedLatLocation = latLng.lat.toString();
        var selectedLongLocation = latLng.lng.toString();

        alert(selectedLatLocation + " " + selectedLongLocation);


      });

      this.map.one(google.maps.event.MAP_READY)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Map is ready!');

        this.map.on(google.maps.event.MAP_CLICK).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                alert("Click MAP");
            }
        );
      });
this.map.setClickable(true);

    });

  }
```

Comment: Where do you set ‚_this‘? Did you mean ‚this‘?

Comment: it's 'this', i have just copied from error that's why. see updates, also the error is in this.map.one and this.map.on, same error. its not a fuction

Comment: You should avoid "this".  The problem is that this means something different inside function initMap than it does for all event handling.  Example: inside a onClick function the this is whichever thing was clicked on.  That conflicts with the this inside initMap

Comment: i have tried by creating local object map inside the method but still i'm getting error like TypeError: map.setClickable is not a function @EmmanuelDelay